# How can I prevent copying/pirating native compiled files (.so file) from my Android APK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, .so

I am using NDK/c++ to do complex calculations in my Android app. After the compilation, .so files are present in the lib folder. I am wondering whether anyone can copy those .so files and use my algorithm in their android app. If possible, how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possibile.

You can:

- check Application's PackageName from your JNI/NDK code to check if it match YOUR specific PackageName
- generate a MD5/SHA of main "*classes.dex*" file and verify this hash from your JNI code (this method is the most secure of them but the most long to be done) and trigger a JVM exit if them doesn't match
- add a cyphed argument on most used JNI method that only your App can encrypt correctly, and then decrypt it from your JNI throwing a JVM exit if the decrypted value is not right